# winforms databinding icon on tag

Tags: winforms, data-binding, .net-2.0

I'm adding a new combobox to a .net 2.0 legacy app that uses data binding via the GUI (ie dropping datasets onto a form and wiring up the properties). I usually bind in code, so I'm not used to this.

I've set up my new field and set all the properties of everything, but the other comboboxes have a tiny database icon in the tag field in properties and mine doesn't. There is no mouseover, tooltip, text or any clue as to what this might mean.

[image]

I assume it means that the field is bound to the underlying dataset, but why only show it on the comboboxes? What on earth does that tiny icon mean?

Comment: You can check also in the properties under the `DataBindings`.

Comment: There isn't a Databindings property on the combobox, form, bindingsource or dataset. Where do I find it?

Comment: oh i see, i don't know in `.net2.0` but in .net later version theres a `DataBindings` Property and you can see the tag and you can remove also.